# How to consume (or iterate over) an array in ATS

Tags: ats

Suppose we declare an array as the following:

```
dataview myarray 
( a:t@ype (* element types *)
, addr (* location *)
, int (* size *)
) =
  | {l:addr}
    myarray_nil(a, l, 0)
  | {l:addr}{n:int}
    myarray_cons(a, l, n + 1) of (a@l, myarray(a, l + sizeof(a), n))
```

I would like to iterate over such an array. I have tried the following way:

```
fun
{a:t@ype}
myarray_map
{l: addr}{n: nat}
(pf: !myarray(a, l, n) | p0: ptr(l), f:a-<cloref1>a): void = let
    prval myarray_cons(pf1, pf2) = pf
    val elm = ptr_get<a>(pf1 | p0)
    val ()  = ptr_set<a>(pf1 | p0, f(elm))
    val p1  = ptr_succ<a>(p0)
in
  (pf:= myarray_cons(pf1, pf2); myarray_map(pf | p1, f))
end
```

The issue is when I hit the myarray_nil case, the prval becomes unmatched.

Since pf is a linear resource, I cannot do

```
case+ pf of
| myarray_nil() =>
| myarray_cons(pf1, pf2) =>
```

Because pf is consumed here but it must be retained according to the function definition. How can I iterate through myarray in this way and ensure that pf is matched exhaustively while not being consumed?

Thank you!

Comment: myarray_map should also take an argument that is the size of the given array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice given in the comments, I wrote the following which typechecks:

```
fun
{a:t@ype}
myarray_map
{l: addr}{n: nat | n > 0}
(pf: !myarray(a, l, n) | p0: ptr(l), n: int(n), f:a-<cloref1>a): void = let
    prval myarray_cons(pf1, pf2) = pf
    val elm = ptr_get<a>(pf1 | p0)
    val ()  = ptr_set<a>(pf1 | p0, f(elm))
    val p1  = ptr_succ<a>(p0)
  in
    if n = 1
    then ()
    else myarray_map(pf2 | p1, n - 1, f); pf := myarray_cons(pf1, pf2)
  end
```